# UpdatePanel returns a error when we click on Linkbutton which is inside UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, linkbutton

i have Linkbutton inside updatePanel and when i click on it it returns following 
error

**An extender can't be in a different UpdatePanel than the control it extends**

so what to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the extender that's extending some control in the other update panel; the error is literally that.  There is an extender in one update panel, but the control it extends is listed in another, or the extender is outside the update panel, or something like that.

HTH.